# htaccess Mod rewrite and permalink

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have a WordPress website where the requirement is exactly like below:

- WordPress site should be installed on: http://www.mydomain.com/wp/ |
- Website homepage should be access from: http://www.mydomain.com/ if someone visits  http://www.mydomain.com/wp/ he should be redirect to http://www.mydomain.com/

But when accessing all other inner pages, visitors should follow the URL format:

- http://www.mydomain.com/wp/test-page1
- http://www.mydomain.com/wp/test-page1

This means I need the main website access from main domain directly but all other inner pages should open under sub-directory as mentioned above.

how can I do that with .htaccess? Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this website about htaccess redirects: http://htaccess.wordpress.com/2008/09/15/redirecting-urls-in-htaccess/

Aside from that, you will want to have your RewriteBase to be / and not wp so that the user doesn't go to wp subfolder automatically.